# How to convert multiple lists into json in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

i have 4 lists 
The "name" List is the unique identifier for all the lists.I am clearing the data on lists Spec_titles,spec_details,varients over a for loop and appending new details on to them

```
name=["Some_car1","Some_car2",..."Some_carx"]
spec_titles=["price", "engine", "bhp","doors" ]
spec_details=["40000$", "1200cc", "125bhp", 5]
varients=["standard","deluxe","premium"]
```

i want to combine all these lists in a json format like below

```
{"vehicledetails":[

  { "Some_car1": {
    "price":"40000$",
    "engine":"1200cc",
    "bhp":"125bhp",
    "doors":"5",
    "varients":"[
        "standard",
        "deluxe",
        "premium"   ]"},
  {"Some_car2":[details]},
  .
  .
  {"Some_carx":[details]}]}
```

i have tried using list-comprehension but couldnot add list varients items into the json, please help me with this problem
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do all cars have the same details?

Comment: no ,diffrent cars have diffrent details, some may have 50 specs_details and 50 spec_titles while some may have 25 spec_details and 25 spec_titles. spec_details and spec_titles will be same number for a car

Comment: so where or how would wee know which data some_car1 gets and what data some_car2 gets?

Comment: like in the list spec_titles will be holding the what specification  it holds and spec_details will be holding the corresponding detail of the specification. like spec_title[0]=spec_details[0]. and i am clearing the details on each list on a for loop and appending new details onto it

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment that you are clearing the spec_details in each loop an repopulating it for new cars you could do something like this. I have populated the spec_details are random for n cars

```py
import json
from random import randint

spec_titles = ["price", "engine", "bhp", "doors"]
varients = ["standard", "deluxe", "premium"]

cars = {}
vehical_data = {"vehicaldetails": [cars]}
for n in range(5):
    name = "some_car" + str(n)
    spec_details = [str(randint(10000, 40000)) + "$", str(randint(600, 1200)) + "cc", str(randint(50, 150)) + "bhp", str(randint(3, 5))]
    car_data = dict(zip(spec_titles, spec_details))
    car_data["varients"] = varients
    cars[name] = car_data

print(json.dumps(vehical_data))
```

**OUTPUT - json pretty format**

```
{
   "vehicaldetails":[
      {
         "some_car0":{
            "price":"27982$",
            "engine":"848cc",
            "bhp":"90bhp",
            "doors":"5",
            "varients":[
               "standard",
               "deluxe",
               "premium"
            ]
         },
         "some_car1":{
            "price":"28400$",
            "engine":"1147cc",
            "bhp":"149bhp",
            "doors":"3",
            "varients":[
               "standard",
               "deluxe",
               "premium"
            ]
         },
         "some_car2":{
            "price":"17148$",
            "engine":"1079cc",
            "bhp":"109bhp",
            "doors":"5",
            "varients":[
               "standard",
               "deluxe",
               "premium"
            ]
         },
         "some_car3":{
            "price":"10831$",
            "engine":"991cc",
            "bhp":"90bhp",
            "doors":"3",
            "varients":[
               "standard",
               "deluxe",
               "premium"
            ]
         },
         "some_car4":{
            "price":"38619$",
            "engine":"1000cc",
            "bhp":"63bhp",
            "doors":"3",
            "varients":[
               "standard",
               "deluxe",
               "premium"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```